# x^2 times convex nonnegative polynomial is convex?

Tags: polynomials, convex-analysis

If $p(x)$ is a convex nonnegative polynomial in $x$, is $x^2 p(x)$ convex?

Its second derivative is
$$
x^2 p''(x) + 4x p'(x) + 2 p(x).
$$
We know $x^2 p''(x)$ is nonnegative by convexity of $p$, and $2p(x)$ is nonnegative by assumption. I don't know how to conclude anything about $x p'(x)$ though.

If the general case is not convex, what about the special case $p(x) = (a + bx)^{2k},\ k \in \mathbb{N},\ a, b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3):

No: for instance, $f(x)=x^2(x-1)^2$ is not convex.  A quick way to see this is that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ but $f$ is strictly positive in between.

More generally, if $p(r)=0$ for some $r\neq 0$ (and $p$ is not identically $0$), then $f(x)=x^2p(x)$ will not be convex since $f(0)=f(r)=0$ but $f$ is positive somewhere between $0$ and $r$.